# Cannot access DirectXMath.h while using DirectX11

Tags: c++, include, directx

i'm currently working on a small 3d game using directx but i'm having some issues with not being able to access the DirectXMath.h file so i can use the inverse function that it contains.
I currently have it included in my "stdafx.h" header. I'm not having any other issues from the other include files that are currently in that file.

Do anyone have any idea why i cannot gain access to the XMMatrixInverse function?
I'm currently using C++.

Comment: What do you mean by can not access? file not found?

Comment: and you'd better provide more info like what error did you get? which version of DX SDK did you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the header is found, you may missing the namespace `using namespace DirectX;`